# По какому принципу нужно составлять словообразовательную цепочку?

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова

По какому принципу нужно составлять словообразовательную цепочку? Что самое главное?

Comment: @telli, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Можно привести такой пример: составить схему для глагола "осушить".

Можно предположить две схемы: сушить - осушить или сухой - осушить.

Вариант 1. Сушить - осушить. Смотрим в словарь: видовая пара сушить - высушить (но не осушить). Приставочный способ предположительно не подходит.

Вариант 2. Сухой - осушить. В словаре: осушить - сделать сухим. Это и есть мотивирующее слово. Тогда словообразовательный формант "приставка О + суффикс И". Его значение: наделить признаком (обогатить, обновить, освежить). Выбираем этот вариант.

Порядок решения

1) В толковом словаре посмотреть значение проверяемого слова, оно определяется через  мотивирующее слово.

2)Определить словообразовательный формант (приставку, суффикс или приставку + суффикс).

3) Проверить значение форманта (определить значение суффикса, приставки или их сочетания, сравнить с другими примерами).

Итак, главное - это правильно найти мотивирующее слово, сделать это нам помогает словарь.

Answer (score 2):

> По какому принципу нужно составлять
> словообразовательную цепочку? Что
> самое главное?

Самое главное -- установить выводимость значения производного слова от однокоренного слова, которое и будет производящим.

К сожалению, толковые словари не всегда нам могут в этом помочь, т. к. не всегда объясняют значение производных слов через производящие. Когда-нибудь они это, возможно, и будут делать. А пока лучше полагаться на свою интуицию.

Попробуем составить словообразовательную цепочку для глагола **осушить.**

В словарях действительно дано:  **сушить** = делать сухим; **высушить**  = сделать совсем сухим. И все вроде бы  согласны с тем, что  **высушить**  -- производное от **сушить.**

А что же такое тогда **осушить?** А **осушить** --  это  сделать сухим. Т. е. практически то же самое, что и **высушить**, только сделать при сушке не совсем сухим, а просто сухим. До нужной степени сухим. И остановить процесс сушки, не доходя до полного высушивания. Ну и почему же нужно разрывать связь глаголов **сушить** и **осушить?**

Конечно же, глагол **осушить** образован приставочным способом от **сушить.**

И словообразовательная цепочка будет выглядеть так:

***сух**(ой) -> суш-**и**-ть ->  **о**-сушить.*

Comment: Обсуждаем проблему, очень интересно. Правда, у меня ответ взят из солидного справочника.

Comment: Уже как-то более менее понятно..я раньше так определяла.Например,цепочка такая-редкий=>редкость=>редкостный.К корню слова-редкий-добавили суффикс -ость,и получили слово-редкость;а к основе слова-редкость-добавили суффикс -н,и получили слово-редкостный.То есть я хочу сказать,например если в словообразовательной цепочке к слову-редкий-добавили суффикс -ость,получилось-редкость..и уже на месте 3-го слова мы не имеем права подставлять такое слово,в котором бы НЕ ИМЕЛСЯ СУФФИКС -ОСТЬ,правильно?

Comment: Всё правильно Вы делаете.Сухой-сушить(сделать сухим)-осушить(довести действие сушить до завершения)-осушение(результат действия по глаголу осушить).Сухой-сушить-высушить(завершить действие сушить)-высушивать(постепенно сушить)-высушивание(результат завершённого действия)

Comment: 
Vera: "у меня ответ взят из солидного справочника."

===

Vera, а название этого "солидного" справочника не подскажете?

Comment: Солидный справочник - это "Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц" Ефремовой, в котором приведены все форманты, в частности формант О...И,  и названо их значение. Вот, к примеру, нельзя сказать, что мы болото сушим, сушим и осушили. Болото мы осушаем, то есть делаем сухим (осушать - осушить). Это ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО, что в словаре для глагола  "сушить" не указывается видовая пара "осушить", но глагол осушить определяется через "сухой". И значение у приставки О - это сделать сухим всё пространство  вокруг, а не полностью обеспечить признак сухости, как у приставки ВЫ в  глаголе "высушить".

Comment: Поэтому мы имеем видовые пары: сушить - высушить, осушить - осушать.

Comment: Vera, завтра посмотрю этот справочник. НЕ ВЕРЮ в то, что Ефремова глагол "высушить" образует от "сушить", а "осушить" от "сухой"! НЕ ВЕРЮ!

P.S. У Тихонова в его "Словообразовательном словаре русского языка" не только "осушить", но и "до/за/ис/на/недо/об/пере/по/под/при/про/у/сушить" -- ВСЕ эти глаголы образуются от "сушить".

Comment: Slava, у Ефремовой приведена схема образования  глаголов освежить, округлить, обновить, остеклить, глагол "осушить" там не указан. Для этого глагола можно предложить две схемы образования. В пользу первой может говорить существование формы "сушить", в пользу второй - семантика и наличие видовой пары осушить - осушать.

Comment: Обратим внимание на то, что ни один из глаголов с разными приставками видовых пар вида "досушить - досушать" не имеет. Только глагола "осушить" не определяется через другие глаголы. Вот в чем, как мне кажется,  интерес вопроса, а не только в поиске готового решения. Я не исключаю формального подхода словарей в данном случае.

Comment: Verа,  "Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц" Ефремовой, в котором приведены все форманты,называет только форманты, их значения,а не говорит, что от чего образуется, это уже Вы так толкуете. Там речь не о цепочке, а просто о смысле. вот у Тихонова - да, словообразовательные цепочки.